# Freeing some memory space on my Amazon Linux 2

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, rhel

I was doing testing on my server and always getting this error

```
 file for here-document: No space left on device
-bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device
```

So I check it with the command "df".

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs         1970540       0   1970540   0% /dev
tmpfs            1988952       0   1988952   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            1988952   65980   1922972   4% /run
tmpfs            1988952       0   1988952   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p1   8376300 8376280        20 100% /
tmpfs             397792      16    397776   1% /run/user/1000
```

I saw that the file /dev/nvme0n1p1 is using most of the memory.
Is there any way I can free those memory? Or what can I do to have free some memory.

Comment: You can increase the volume size. Why not do that?

Comment: Yeah Im thinking about that option. So basically, I removed already some unused packages and it went to 93%

Comment: Is there a way to used other filesystem? I can see that they have availble spaces

Comment: The only other mount points are using ram, so while you can use them, you'd probably hit bigger problems pretty fast if you put any serious amount of data in them.  You either need to delete files on your disk, or increase the size of the disk.  Or both.

Comment: This question would probably fit better to SuperUser or ServerFault forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To free memory you can do the following:

1. Check log files located in `/var/log` and empty any big log files.
2. Install and configure `logrotate` tool to make sure that logs are will not consume disk space specially if you are using any webserver "Nginx, Apache for example".
3. Remove unused packages and delete unused files.
4. Use `find` command as the following:
   `find / -size +100M | xargs du -sch` this command will list big files and show it's size.

Comment: One more good tool is command `du -h --max-depth 1`. It shows directories had how each child in a directory consumes space. That way you find directories full of small log fies consuming lot of space.